# When is the ring of continuous functions Noetherian?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Is there any topological property on $X$ that be equivalent to $C(X,\mathbb R)$ being a noetherian ring?

Comment: What continuous functions? Between what and what?...

Comment: ay ay ay, what a mess.

Comment: It's certainly clearer, but is it a legitimate edit? @JonathanY., how do you know this is what OP meant?

Comment: @tomasz because OP posted a duplicate. I flagged that for moderation and also explained what happened in a request to reopen on meta.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to the space $C(X)$ of continuous complex/real valued functions on some compact Hausdorff space $X$. Check that:

1. If $X$ is finite, then $C(X)$ is Noetherian.
2. If $R$ is a commutative ring, let $Y := \text{mspec}(R)$, the collection of maximal ideals of $R$ with the Zariski topology. If $R$ is Noetherian, then every subset of $Y$ is compact. In particular, if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ is finite.
3. If $R = C(X)$, then $\text{mspec}(R) \cong X$.

Conclude that, $C(X)$ is Noetherian iff $X$ is finite.

Comment: What about when we do not assume $X$ is compact? The ring is well-defined in any case.