# Noetherianty of ring of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Is there any topological property on $X$ that be equivalent to $C(X,\mathbb R)$ be noetherian ring?

Comment: Please edit your [original](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570030/when-is-the-ring-of-continuous-functions-noetherian) question instead of reposting; if nothing else, you already have a partial answer there.